# Datagrid cell tooltip and foreground setting in CellEditEnding - it's moving, why?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, tooltip, element

I'm using the **CellEditEnding** event for setting new **foreground color** and **tooltip** for editted cells. It works quite ok, except why I scroll down in the datagrid the foreground colour and tooltip moves in the column and that makes it quite useless.

I think it must be something with the **FrameWork element** but I'm quite not sure how to solve this problem.

### My code:

```
private void myDataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
  {
  
    System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip tt = new System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip();
    tt.Content = "My tooltip text";
    FrameworkElement element = (e.Column.GetCellContent(e.Row));
    System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell chosen = (element.Parent as System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell);
    chosen.ToolTip = tt;
    chosen.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
  }
```

Can anyone tell me why it's moving(the tooltip and color) to other cells when scrolling in the datagrid? And how shoud I solve it?

Or if you have better idea on how to set the tooltip and foreground color for editted cells in datagrid, please tell me.

Thanks for any help in advance ;)

Comment: I didn't work a lot with wpf by now. But why do you use a FrameworkElement. Isn't it possible to access the cell like the following code (for winForm): dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Blue;

Comment: It's WPF not winforms.. not so simple :|

Comment: But you have something like a datagridview object right ?

Comment: I do have http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx but the thing is it doesn't work exactly like winforms datagridview, so if you haven't worked with WPF you can't help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
<DataGrid Name="SimpleDataGrid" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" CellEditEnding="SimpleDataGrid_CellEditEnding" />
```

for scrolls in terms of **physical** units.

For more information see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.cancontentscroll.aspx).